# chrome fails to export crm 2013 solution

Tags: export, dynamics-crm-2013

I have been exporting and importing CRM 2013 solutions for our project over the last year with Chrome.

All of a sudden from this week, this now fails.
I go through all the prompts to select Managed solution, select version, etc.  And when I click Export, the screen just closes and then nothing.

Anyone else experiencing this recently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest Google Chrome version (37) removed the `showModalDialog` API.

You need to enable it again using a Group Policy or use another browser.

Details here: [The (browser compatibility) cake is a lie](http://www.crmanswers.net/2014/09/the-browser-compatibility-cake-is-lie.html)

Also a registry fix is available: [Google Chrome registry fix for Dynamics CRM 2011/2013](http://www.crmanswers.net/2014/09/google-chrome-registry-fix-for-dynamics.html)

Comment: Thank you Guido.

This makes sense and I thought it was a change from google.